# Easy wrapper for optparse to argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, optparse

I have a mix of libraries in the same codebase, some using argparse and others using optparse.

I'd like to integrate all of the options into a master configuration tool - ideally, without going in and editing the various libraries and tools.

Is it possible to wrap (or otherwise integrate) an optparse options object into an argparse parser, such that the parser is extended with the optparse options (and conflicts are highlighted etc...)?

Comment: The short answer is, no, `argparse` doesn't have any function that accepts an `OptionParser` instance as an argument and returns an equivalent `ArgumentParser` instance. Any longer answer would simply be a recommendation for a 3rd-party library that *does* provide such a function.

Comment: hum. doesn't look too hard for argparse to have an optparse wrapper (unless i'm missing something?)

Comment: Just write one yourself - the biggest task would be extracting the relevant parameters from the optparse parser.  Once you have a compatible set of parameters you can easily create a new argparse argument.  There are guidelines at the end of the argparse docs for translating optparse arguments into argparse ones.  Give a concrete example if you want more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a simple `optparse` parser; here are the attributes of the objects

```
In [229]: parser = OptionParser()
In [230]: parser
Out[230]: <optparse.OptionParser at 0xaf912a4c>
In [231]: parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
     ...:                   help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
Out[231]: <Option at 0xaf919b2c: -f/--file>
In [232]: parser.option_list
Out[232]: [<Option at 0xaf91232c: -h/--help>, <Option at 0xaf919b2c: -f/--file>]

In [233]: vars(parser.option_list[1])
Out[233]: 
{'_long_opts': ['--file'],
 '_short_opts': ['-f'],
 'action': 'store',
 'callback': None,
 'callback_args': None,
 'callback_kwargs': None,
 'choices': None,
 'const': None,
 'container': <optparse.OptionParser at 0xaf912a4c>,
 'default': ('NO', 'DEFAULT'),
 'dest': 'filename',
 'help': 'write report to FILE',
 'metavar': 'FILE',
 'nargs': 1
 'type': 'string'}

In [234]: vars(parser)
Out[234]: 
{'_long_opt': {'--file': <Option at 0xaf919b2c: -f/--file>,
  '--help': <Option at 0xaf91232c: -h/--help>},
 '_short_opt': {'-f': <Option at 0xaf919b2c: -f/--file>,
  '-h': <Option at 0xaf91232c: -h/--help>},
 'allow_interspersed_args': True,
 'conflict_handler': 'error',
 'defaults': {'filename': None},
 'description': None,
 'epilog': None,
 'formatter': <optparse.IndentedHelpFormatter at 0xaf8feb0c>,
 'largs': None,
 'option_class': optparse.Option,
 'option_groups': [],
 'option_list': [<Option at 0xaf91232c: -h/--help>,
  <Option at 0xaf919b2c: -f/--file>],
 'process_default_values': True,
 'prog': None,
 'rargs': None,
 'usage': '%prog [options]',
 'values': None,
 'version': None}
```

The 'wrapper' would have to do something like:

```
In [252]: pa = argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [253]: a1=parser.option_list[1]
In [254]: assert(a1.action=='store')
In [255]: ostrings=[]
In [256]: ostrings.extend(a1._short_opts)
In [257]: ostrings.extend(a1._long_opts)
In [259]: assert(a1.const is None)
In [260]: ohelp=a1.help
In [261]: odest=a1.dest
In [262]: ometa=a1.metavar

In [264]: pa.add_argument(*ostrings, dest=odest, metavar=ometa, help=ohelp)
Out[264]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--file'],
  dest='filename', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None,
  choices=None, help='write report to FILE', metavar='FILE')
```

Compare the helps:

```
In [265]: pa.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f FILE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILE, --file FILE  write report to FILE

In [267]: parser.print_help()
Usage: ipython3 [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILE, --file=FILE  write report to FILE
```

But even if you wrote such a converter, how would it fit in a work flow?  Would it robust enough to incorporate in the runtime?